# Create/Update method not allowed in "Activity Pointer" CRM 2011

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

Am having a plugin that moves the activities of lead to opportunity on qualify. I have registered the plugin on "Create" of opportunity and the following is the code

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)   
{
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
        Entity entity;

        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            if (entity.Attributes.Contains("originatingleadid") == false) return;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
          //.....

            EntityReference Lead = (EntityReference)entity.Attributes["originatingleadid"];
            Guid LeadGuid = Lead.Id;
            MoveActivitiesFromLeadToOpportunity(service, LeadGuid, Opportunityid);
        }
        catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(
            "An error occurred in the plug-in.", ex);
        }
    }
 private void MoveActivitiesFromLeadToOpportunity(IOrganizationService service, Guid LeadID, Guid OpportunityID)
    {    
        ConditionExpression condition = new ConditionExpression();
        condition.AttributeName = "regardingobjectid";
        condition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;
        condition.Values.Add(LeadID.ToString());
        var query = new QueryExpression("activitypointer");
        query.Criteria.AddCondition(condition);
        //query.Conditions.Add("reagrdingobjectid", ConditionOperator.Equal, theIdOfTheRelatedRecord);
        query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);

        var activities = service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities;
        foreach (var activity in activities)
        {
            var castedActivity = (ActivityPointer)activity;
           if (castedActivity.ActivityTypeCode == "email")
            {
                castedActivity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                castedActivity["regardingobjectid"] = new EntityReference("opportunity", OpportunityID);
                //service.Create(castedActivity);--->Exception thrown
                //service.Update(castedActivity);---->Tried this one too.Exception is thrown stating method not supported on "ActivityPointer"
            }


        }
```

Can somebody shed light on this? Am i missing something here? Thank you

Comment: Don't the Lead's emails move over to the Opportunity on Qualify anyway?  Not sure why you'd need to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to query for the exact entity type, because you can't update an `activitypointer`

```cs
private void MoveEmailsFromLeadToOpportunity(IOrganizationService service, Guid LeadID, Guid OpportunityID)
    {    
        ConditionExpression condition = new ConditionExpression();
        condition.AttributeName = "regardingobjectid";
        condition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;
        condition.Values.Add(LeadID.ToString());
        var query = new QueryExpression("email");
        query.Criteria.AddCondition(condition);
        query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);

        var emails = service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities;
        foreach (var email in emails)
        {
            email["regardingobjectid"] = new EntityReference("opportunity", OpportunityID);
            service.Update(email);
        }
    }
```

you can also write a method that will retrieve first all the activities (as you already did) check the `ActivityTypeCode` after retrieve and update each single record depending on activity type (email, fax, ...)

Comment: probably you registered the plugin as pre-operation synchronous, at that point the record is not created yet, try to register as post-operation asynchronous

Comment: Sorry.. deleted the comment by mistake..Yeah..Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out this line:

```
castedActivity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

And then just do your `Update`:

```
service.Update(castedActivity)
```

You are just updating the `RegardingObjectId`, not creating a new activity, so you shouldn't change the Id and you shouldn't use `Create`.

Comment: I commented the line mentioned,but am getting the following error " The 'Update' method does not support entities of type 'activitypointer'"