# CRM 2011 accessing webcontext with outlook plugin

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, outlook-addin, microsoft-dynamics

I have found some plugin code on the web that enables me to get the entity ID and the object type code for an entity in a plugin.  The plugin is fired on RetrieveMultiple on activitypointer. The code lets me get the id and object code of the entity that is currently being viewed (which is displaying the activities grid which is firing the plugin).

This code works fine when using the web interface.  However I need it to also work in the Outlook preview pane and currently it does not.  The activities grid in the Outlook preview pane just says "an error has occurred".  Below is the code that the plugin is using to get the details from the web header.

```
    internal static Dictionary<string, string> GetHeaderFields(HttpContext webcontext, string objectTypeCode, string objectId)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string callerentitytype = null;
        string callerentityidstring = null;
        try
        {
            // Activities Navigation Pane
            if (new List<string>(webcontext.Request.Params.AllKeys).Contains("oType"))
            {
                callerentitytype = webcontext.Request.Params["oType"];
                callerentityidstring = webcontext.Request.Params["oId"];
            }
            // Activities Sub Grid
            else
            {
                string requeststring = webcontext.Request.UrlReferrer.Query;
                requeststring = requeststring.Substring(1);

                string[] parts = requeststring.Split(new string[] { "=", "&" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length - 1; i++)
                    if (parts[i].ToLower() == "otype" || parts[i].ToLower() == "etc")
                        callerentitytype = parts[i + 1];
                    else if (parts[i].ToLower() == "oid" || parts[i].ToLower() == "id")
                        callerentityidstring = parts[i + 1];
            }

            fields.Add(objectTypeCode, callerentitytype);
            fields.Add(objectId, callerentityidstring);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Plugin.LoggableException(string.Format("Failed to obtain header information; {0}", ex.Message), ex.InnerException);
        }

        return fields;
    }
```

The reason is that webcontext.Request.UrlReferrer is NULL. Is there anywhere else I can get this info of the 'calling' entity?  (Not the activity sub grid that is triggering the plugin, but the actual parent entity that the sub grid is on).

Thanks for any help or direction with this.

Answer (score 0):

This *might* work. Each of the activitypointers that are returned should all be "regarding" the same record (if in a sub grid). If you take say the 1st one and examine the regardingobjectid property, that should be an entity reference which will give you the logical name of the parent and it's guid. If that works, it will work across all clients (in theory anyway).

Comment: I don't think its an entityreference, I think its a guid.

Comment: I don't have a crm instance I can access to check but if it is only a guid, then you can use the type code + guid to retrieve the actual activity and from that I believe it holds an entref to the parent record. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907988/create-update-method-not-allowed-in-activity-pointer-crm-2011) for related info